# Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in NameModel#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After creating a migration I get this error:

4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
   Your manifest contains:
   {
   }

```
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    </head>
    
<body>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you add more details?

Comment: Hi friend! Thanks for answerme. What i did was delete Webpacker completely and install it again